# Update database with submission form

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I've been trying to figure out why my database won't update! I know i'm doing something wrong but I don't know what's wrong! here's my code! please help.

```
        $user_id = (int)$user['id'];
        $editName = $user['full_name'];
        $editEmail = $user['email'];
        $editPermissions = $user['permissions'];

        if(isset($_POST['editUser'])){

        $editName = $_POST['editname'];
        $editEmail = $_POST['editemail'];
        $editPermissions = $_POST['editpermissions'];

            $db->query("UPDATE users SET full_name = '$editName',email = '$editEmail', permissions = '$editPermissions' WHERE id = '$user_id'");

            }

     ?>
        <form action="users.php" method="post">
        <td><input type="text" name="editname" id="editname" class="form-control col-sm-2" value="<?=$editName;?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="editemail" id="editemail" class="form-control col-sm-2" value="<?=$editEmail;?>"></td>
        <td><?=pretty_date($user['join_date']);?></td>
        <td><?=(($user['last_login'] == '0000-00-00 00:00:00')?'never':pretty_date($user['last_login']));?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="editpermissions" id="editpermissions" class="form-control col-sm-2" 
        value="<?=$editPermissions;?>"></td>    
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-right button">
        <a href="users.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
        <input type="submit" name="editUser" value="Edit User" class="btn btn-success">
        </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: <?php if(isset($_GET['edit']) && $_GET['edit'] == $user['id']):

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the id of the user in the form.

Add

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $user_id ?>" />
```

Add this to your second `if(){}`

```
$user_id = $_POST['id'];
```

As a side note, you should not be using `<td>` in a `<form>` if they're not in a `<tr>` and the non-existant `<tr>` is not in a `<table>`. Have a look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

Next up, you're `<input>`'s also do not have a `<label>` (matched together using `for` and `id` attributes). [Look at this](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/elements/7-label.html)

Last up, you're `<input type="submit" name="editUser" value="Edit User" class="btn btn-success">` could be replaced using a `<button>` element. As you're using Bootstrap you could find a proper [submit button here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons)

Lastly, the way the code is written is pretty unreadable. [Please read this](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), commit it to memory and use it ;)

Comment: Thanks for responding! I fixed the code by adding this to my form 

 <form action="users.php?edit=<?=$user_id?>" method="post">    
and now i can update the database with the input form! 

I've been trying to figure this out all day yesterday thank u for your help!       Also, this isn't the whole code, this is only the half where I needed help with. The form is inside a table, the form pops up when the user presses the edit button. Thanks again!

Comment: Excellent and glad to help. If the answer answered your question though, could you mark it as an answer? :)